# Run the task scheduler once a day but not hourly intervals

Tags: windows

I want to schedule a job(process).Job should run only once in day at 9:30 AM.

Thanks Advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Windows button + R then type taskschd.msc

from the right top side choose, create task.

from top menu choose trigger.

make the settings as below screenshot.
[trigger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjCo4.jpg)